# ColdFusion ReMatchNoCase

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am parsing a string which has some repeated object called Persons.
So I was using a ReFindNocase to get the 1st one and then I was using a loop to get the others. (I need also the position and the leg for each person-string).
Then I found out RematchNocase but it only returns the strings-persons not the position.
Is there any compination of these two? Eg: Return a struct with len and pos for each match.

Comment: Natively? No. But it's easy enough to roll-your own (although look on cflib.org first). It might also help to go vote for this: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3321666

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some sample data with your question.

Comment: (From now deleted answer) *[ReFindNoCase] is what I am using right now. With Refindnocase I have to loop through the text* There are no CF functions which provide both the text and position, so you must DIY (loop + reFindNoCase, regex, etcetera).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you found what you were looking for, and without some sample data to work with, it's tough to say if this will suffice, but this might work for you.

```
<cfscript>
  function ReFindAll(rex,str) {
    if (not len(arguments.rex)) {
      return {len = [], rex = [], matches = [], err = "Regular Expression Empty"};
    }
    local.Coords = {len = [], pos = [], matches = []};
    local.finding = -1;
    local.findset =  "";
    while (finding neq 0) {
        findset = ReFindNoCase(arguments.rex,arguments.str,finding,true);
        if (finding eq findset.pos[1] + findset.len[1]) {
          return {len = [], rex = [], matches = [], err = "Regex has infinite matches."};
        }
        if (findset.len[1] gt 0) {
         ArrayAppend(Coords.pos,findset.pos);
         ArrayAppend(Coords.len,findset.len);
         ArrayAppend(Coords.matches,mid(arguments.str,findset.pos[1],findset.len[1]));
        }
        finding = findset.pos[1] + findset.len[1];
    }
    return coords;
  }
  cogs = ReFindAll("name\d","name1 = bob name2 = joe name3 = steve");
  writedump(cogs);
</cfscript>
```

It does some validation to make sure that the regex has some content, any content and it further protects against regexes that will infinitely loop on the same point (without the safeguard, `.*?` by itself will capture 0 characters and continue to return 0 characters infinitely, until the server times out or errors out).